# Cancellation of addition on convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-analysis

I [recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174997/36492) found a question about a property of the [Minkowski sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition). However the question was not properly answered (it used a projection argument which might not be true in a general Banach space).

I was wondering whether the following (weaker) statement holds:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and suppose $A,B,C_0\subset X$ are bounded, closed, convex and non-empty subset. Do we then have $$A+C_0=B+C_0\implies A=B?$$

Comment: what is the difference with that question?

Comment: There is an equality symbol instead of an inclusion, which makes this statement stronger

Comment: This statement is weaker, not stronger. Yours immediately follows from the other one (as shown in the answer) while the other one doesn't follow from yours. I find it objectionable to call the other question not properly answered, as the easy fix was presented in a comment while joriki's answer gave the important geometric intuition.

Comment: I've now fixed [my answer to the other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/175016/6622).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo result presented in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174997/36492) question the solution is extremely simple
$$
A+C_0=B+C_0\Longleftrightarrow (A+C_0\subset B+C_0)\wedge(B+C_0\subset A+C_0)\Longrightarrow
$$
$$
(A\subset B)\wedge (B\subset A)\Longleftrightarrow A=B
$$